# How to screen scrape across origins in an IFRAME?

Tags: javascript, iframe, xss, browser-security

I have a business web app that needs to pull in information from various other web sites. For most sites, the user just instructs the server to pull the data (either using .NET's HttpRequest, or Selenium).

But for some unfriendly, Javascript-heavy sites, our users have to visit the site manually, navigate to the right spot, and copy and paste into our application.

Other than bookmarklets, is there **any way** for our page to show an IFRAME with the source web site loaded, allow the user to navigate within the frame, and then capture the IFRAME's body?

Since the site in the IFRAME isn't in the same domain (not even close), I can't seem to work around browser cross-site scripting limitations. I've tried using HTML5's "sandbox" feature, but it appears to only allow communication (via "allow-same-origin") the *other* way, from the IFRAME to the host site, which isn't useful to me. Also, it doesn't work if the site in question attempts to load its frames to the top context.

What I'm ideally looking for is a solution that would allow the browser to be configured to trust my web site implicitly (it's an intranet app) and allow it to access any frame's contents. That would at least get me in the ballpark. Bonus points if I can get the iframe to redefine the "top" context as its own frame, so the hosted site functions properly within the frame.

Comment: What Google Analytics does for their In Page Analytics feature is they use the Google Analytics script that the page has in order to communicate with the page (using `postMessage`, I assume).

Comment: It is called do it on the server. The security is there for a reason. Imagine if I could get around it and read your email/bank account. Other choice is to use a service like Yahoo Pipes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach I've found through many many screen scraping projects (scraping JS heavy pages) is to create a user-script or Greasemonkey script, setup a few virtual machines in their own IP space (for protection) and feed them a list of sites to visit from a remote program:

1. Check the queue at a set interval
2. Request page with Greasemonkey, etc.
3. Capture contents and send to remote program for processing

You can't use an iframe method and you are going to bang your head up against a wall trying to go that route, the method I've described has worked for numerous large-scale scraping projects.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I've been using bookmarklets as a poor man's Greasemonkey, the bookmarklet creates its own form inside the target page and posts the HTML to my site. I'll keep GM-in-VM in mind for some similar work that is more script-friendly.

Comment: No problem, these kinds of tasks have been some of my favorite! :) Good luck with your project